# Galaxy S2 stuck in boot loop (nor reco, no safe mode working)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot-loop, heimdall

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 that when hot after intensive use, the day after while rebooting it got stuck to the Samsung initial logo screen and could never start again.

I have tried the boot tricks :
- Safe mode: won't go pass the logo screen (tried power + menu)
- Recovery mode: won't start either (tried volue up+menu+power)
--> When doing that the screen goes black, the phone looks to be off
--> There is no SD card in the phone, is it required ?

I tried before those action to do both a soft reset and hard reset to no effect.

The only thing i can get the phone to is the odin mode (volume down + home + power)
From there i used Heimdall to check if the device was detected and it was, i could even download the pit file (but don't know how to check it's content). I was thinking of doing a dump, but this option have been removed since it was not effective.

This being the situation, the phone have not been backed up (nor locally, nor online) and I wish to recover the address book (and optionally SMS) so I would like to try all option that would allow me to keep those data before trying anything destructive.

Any hint, help and ideas would be appreciated,
Thank you in advance